# How (if possible) to change modification date of folder to past?

Tags: nautilus, filesystem

I have large number of files and folders in a separate partition and I need them to be ordered by creation/modification time (in Nautilus I click on the "View items as list" button and on "Modified" colum to get this done). Few days ago I saw a sub-folder, that was not needed, in one of them and I deleted it. But that also changed the modification date of folder that contained it. Now this folder is at the top of the list.

It is not a big deal, but it got me wondering if there is a way to revert to previous modification date.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about reverting to the previous modification date, but you can certainly set it to an arbitrary date: `touch -t` or `touch -d`. Check `man touch` for the format to use, and choose between `-t` or `-d`.

For example, to set the last modification time on a directory called `Downloads` to 5th December 2016 at 12:30 you'd use:

```
touch -t 201612051230 Downloads
```

Comment: Works nice. Thank you. I know touch command but I didn't know about this option. For some reason I thought it will be more difficult. I will wait a bit if someone knows how to get previous modification date, otherwise I will mark your answer as Accepted.